# 500 (Internal Server Error) on $dom->loadXML

Tags: php, dom

I have some php code on my website that is producing a 500 error when I try to access it. I believe it's something i'm doing with $dom->loadXML($file).

Here is edit_test.php

```
<?php
    include_once('xmlSplit.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <?php
            foreach($output as $Test_Step){?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editform">
                        <input type="number" style="width: 30px;" value="<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>" onblur="update_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>()" id="Test_Step_Number_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td class="editform">
                        <textarea class="editor" id="Test_Step_Description_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>" onblur="update_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>()"><?php echo trim($Test_Step[2]); ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td class="editform">
                        <textarea class="editor" id="Test_Step_Expected_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>" onblur="update_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>()"><?php echo trim($Test_Step[3]); ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td class="editform">
                        <button id="deletestep_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>" class="SquareDelete" onclick="delete_<?php echo trim($Test_Step[1]); ?>()">
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            $Additional_id = trim($Test_Step[1]) + 1;
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="editform">
                <input type="number" style="width: 30px;" id="New_Step_Number" placeholder="#" value="<?php echo $Additional_id; ?>">
            </td>
            <td class="editform">
                <textarea class="editor" id="New_Step_Description" placeholder="New Step Description"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td class="editform">
                <textarea class="editor" id="New_Step_Expected" placeholder="New Step Expected Result"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td class="editform">
                <input type="submit" class="largeRectButton" value="Add Step" id="insert_new_step" onclick="insert_new_step()">
                <br />
                <input type="submit" class="largeRectButton" value="Save And Exit" id="insert_new_step" onclick="saveChanges()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

that uses include to include the file xmlSplit.php:

```
<?php

    //Decide which version of the file that we need to open
    if(isset($_GET['mode'])){
        //Give the variables an easier name
        $mode = $_GET['mode'];
        $file = $_GET['file'];

        if($mode == 1){
            //This will open the blank test case

            $file = ('../files/tests/' . $file . '.txt');
    } elseif($mode == 2){
        //This will open a previous test run
        $file = ('../files/test_runs/' . $file . '.txt');
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: 2 - Mode not recognised";
        die();
    }


} else {
    echo "ERROR: 1 - Mode not specified";
    die();
};

$xml = file_get_contents($file);


$indexes = [];
$numbers = [];
$descriptions = [];
$expecteds = []; 
$run_times = [];
$run_statuses = [];
$observations = [];
$comments = [];

$output = [];

$dom = new DOMDOCUMENT;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'index' ) as $item ) { 
    $indexes[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'number' ) as $item ) {
    $numbers[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'description' ) as $item ) {
    $descriptions[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'expected' ) as $item ) {
    $expecteds[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'run_time' ) as $item ) {
    $expecteds[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'expected' ) as $item ) {
    $expecteds[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'observations' ) as $item ) {
    $observations[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'run_status' ) as $item ) {
    $run_statuses[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'run_time' ) as $item ) {
    $run_times[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'review' ) as $item ) {
    $comments[] = $dom->saveXML( $item );
}

foreach($indexes as $index){
    //Make the indexes readable
    $index = substr($index, 7, -8);
    $index = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $index));    

    //Parse things so it's just the values without the tags
    $number = substr($numbers[$index], 8, -9);
    $number = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $number));
    $description = substr($descriptions[$index], 13, -14);
    $description = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $description));
    $expected = substr($expecteds[$index], 10, -11);
    $expected = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $expected));
    $observation = substr($observations[$index], 14, -15);
    $observation = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $observation));
    $run_status = substr($run_statuses[$index], 12, -13);
    $run_status = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $run_status));
    $run_time = substr($run_times[$index], 10, -11);
    $run_time = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $run_time));
    $comment = substr($comments[$index], 9, -10);
    $comment = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $comment));

    //Push this step to the output
    array_push($output, $index);
    array_push($output, $number);
    array_push($output, $description);
    array_push($output, $expected);
    array_push($output, $observation);
    array_push($output, $run_status);
    array_push($output, $run_time);
    array_push($output, $comment);
}

//Split the output so they are all matching whats expected
$output = array_chunk($output, 8);

$size = sizeof($output);

    //If the debug was set, print it on the screen, otherwise do nothing as we assume this script is running in the background
    if(isset($_GET['debug'])){
        echo ( "<pre>" . print_r($output, true) . "</pre>");
    }
?>
```

which is working OK on my development server (XAMPP) but when I put it on my "production" environment, I just get a 500 internal server error in the javascript console. I don't understand why.

edit_test.php is contained within an iframe.

There's javascript for loading different files, this is all working, and I have no problems with it on the development server. The complete code can be found on github {LINK REDACTED} if you wish to put it on a development server of your own to have a look and see it all works. (you will need a mysql database server to connect to, database setup in the /database_changes/ folder, connection in /backend_scripts/database_connection.php

i've even tried manually calling xmlSplit.php with all the variables I need in the url but I have had the same problem (500 internal server error)

yes PHP is running on the server, the versions:

development: PHP 7.1.9

production:  7.1.8-1

the XML is structured OK and all the permissions are OK.

my production server is at {LINK REDACTED} and the username is "tester" with password "test"

Comment: check the error log, you'll see a message there telling you what's up

Comment: @giorgio do you mean the php error log or the apache one?

Comment: Wait, they're set to the same place and there's things there. I'll investigate, thanks.

Comment: check both. Probably it's something with php, but it could be anything, eg. malformed .htaccess or whatever.

Comment: It looks like i'm missing the php-xml extension on production server. Will install - need repo update first.

Comment: yeah, sounds like it. fyi; checking the error log should be your first reflex when you see a 500 error. 99% of the error messages are self-explanatory and can be fixed easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160688/discussion-between-harvey-fletcher-and-giorgio).